# Use Guice to inject RequestObject

Tags: rest, parameters, httprequest, guice

I am fairly new to Guice Dependency Injection. My application class get a request object that I want to delegate to my validator, transformer and publisher.

I don't want to send the request object to each of the components (validator, transformer and publisher) instead if I want to use guice to inject the request object in each component.

I know I could do it with AssistedInject by building separate factories for each of the components.

But is it a good idea to inject a runtime parameter?
Is there a way to do it with AssistedInject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency injection is a very nice way to set up your static dependencies ... so basically you have some stateless workers that need to communicate and you set them up via guice.

The runtime behavior (working with request/response or user input) is best handled with parameterized methods on those static workers.

You can however use RequestScope to isolate runtime-values from static setup ... but that depends on your use case and if its your first time using guice/DI, I would stick to the simple approach.